# Unable to select the master object in Process builder

Tags: apex, process-builder

I have a custom object Package__c in master-detail relation ship with the account object.

I am creating a process on Package__c object and the action should update the account object record but I am not able to select the account object in process builder.

Here are the screenshots:

[image]
[image]

Here in the second screenshot, I am not able to select the account object.I tried clicking on the Account Name but choose button is not highlighted.

Any help on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are selecting the hyperlink which leads to the fields inside the object Account Name. Instead you should select Account Name without hyperlink(> symbol). Scroll down a little further probably & you can find it.

Answer (score 1):

Please select as shown below. I have created a process on contact where Account is parent. You need to select Account without (>) sign

[image]

[image]